# Link chart heading to cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I would like the main heading of a Google Sheets chart to change dynamically by linking it to the value of a cell. The header input field does however not seem to handle formulas like `=I4`, it just displays the formula.

Is there a way to link a chart heading to a cell value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set title of currently selected chart from named cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/114561/set-title-of-currently-selected-chart-from-named-cell)